# A word / idiom for "living a normal life, like everyone else"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idioms, idiom-requests

A4 is the [standard size of a sheet of paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_216) (anywhere but the USA, Canada, Mexico and the Dominican Republic).

In Norwegian, there's an idiom, "The A4 life". It means something like:

> You work 8-4 in a fairly common profession, have a house, one or two cars, a spouse, and one or more children. You don't do anything extraordinary, you've settled down, and live life like everyone else.

Note: It doesn't mean you live a boring life, and it's not necessarily negative. It means that *on paper*, your life is just like everyone else's. Note that the part about having a spouse and children is essential.

Is there a word, idiom or phrase that describes this in English?

Comment: An ordinary life.

Comment: But you can live an ordinary life if you're single too, or? The part about having a spouse and children is essential.

Comment: "The full catastrophe"--Zorba the Greek

Answer (score 2):

That's a great phrase! I can't think of a direct analogue in English, but the closest is probably to have **[settled down](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/settle_down)**: to have 'establish[ed] a settled lifestyle, and especially to [have] marr[ied].' A more interesting idiom is to have **[2.4 children](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/2.4_children)**: to have an average or conventional family life, by reference to the supposed average number of children per family in the UK. Someone with 2.4 children probably also has a **[9 to 5](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/9_to_5)** (this can be used without the suffix 'job' and doesn't necessarily mean that they actually work from 9 am to 5 pm).

Answer (score 2):

You might call an average person a common name like **John Doe** (also **Jane Doe**) or **John Smith**.

A **white picket fence** is a symbol of an ordinary life. You could say "living a white picket fence life."

An **Average Joe** (US) or an **Ordinary Joe** (UK) is another name for an archetypical person.

Answer (score 1):

We sometimes utilize the latin term ***status quo*** when referencing someone's life attributes in comparison to an average.  For example, a thirty-something year old in the middle of his career working standard or regular hours, living in an cozy house, possibly married with about 2 children, might have a ***status quo*** life.

Other expressions include the terms ***2.4 children***, ***John/Jane Doe***, ***middle-class***, ***9 to 5***, ***ordinary***, ***bread-and-butter***, and especially in America, ***living the American dream*** or ***living a white picket fence life***.